# Не могу найти ошибку в php

Tags: php

Не могу найти ошибку в php. Помогите пожалуйста?!

```
<?php
function register_user($register_data) {
    array_walk($register_data, 'array_sanitize');
    $register_data['password'] = md5($register_data['password']);

    $fields = '`' . implode('`, `', array_keys($register_data)) . '`';
    $data = '\'' . implode('\', \'', $register_data) . '\'';

    $insert = "INSERT INTO users($fields) VALUES ($data) ";
    mysqli_query($con,$insert);
    $last_id = mysqli_insert_id($con);
    $update = "UPDATE users SET url = '".$last_id."' WHERE id = ".$last_id." ";
    mysqli_query($con,$update );
}
?>
```

**UPDATE**

```
<?php
include 'core/init.php';

if (empty($_POST) === false) {
    $required_fields = array('username', 'password', 'password_again', 'first_name', 'email');
    foreach($_POST as $key=>$value) {
        if (empty($value) && in_array($key, $required_fields) === true) {
            $errors[] = '<div id="result_x"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></div><div id="error">Заполните все поля чтобы продолжить регистрацию.</div>';
                break 1;
        }
    }

    if (empty($errors) === true) {
        if (user_exists($_POST['username']) === true) {
            $errors[] = '<div id="result_x"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></div><div id="error">К сожалению, имя пользователя <b>' . $_POST['username'] . '</b> уже используется.</div>';
        }
        if (preg_match("/\\s/", $_POST['username']) == true) {
            $errors[] = '<div id="result_x"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></div><div id="error">Ваш имя пользователя не должно содержать пробелов.</div>';
        }
        if (strlen($_POST['password']) < 6) {
            $errors[] = '<div id="result_x"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></div><div id="error">Ваш пароль должен быть не менее 6 символов.</div>';
        }
        if ($_POST['password'] !== $_POST['password_again']) {
            $errors[] = '<div id="result_x"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></div><div id="error">Ваш пароли не совпадают.</div>';
        }
        if (filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
            $errors[] = '<div id="result_x"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></div><div id="error">Действительный адрес электронной почты требуется.</div>';
        }
        if (email_exists($_POST['email']) === true) {
            $errors[] = '<div id="result_x"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></div><div id="error">К сожалению, электронной почты <b>' . $_POST['email'] . '</b> уже используется.</div>';
        }
    }
}
?>
<?php
if (empty($_POST) === false && empty($errors) === true) {
    $register_data = array(
        'username'   => $_POST['username'],
        'password'   => $_POST['password'],
        'first_name' => $_POST['first_name'],
        'last_name'  => $_POST['last_name'],
        'email'      => $_POST['email']
    );

    register_user($register_data);
    echo '<div id="result_x"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></div><div id="error">Вы были успешно зарегистрирован!</div>';
} else if (empty($errors) === false) {
    echo output_errors($errors);
}
?>
```

Comment: А какая ошибка-то появляется?

Comment: @ZhukovRoman, наоборот ничего не бывает :)

Comment: А что за callback функция у вас используется? В ней всё в порядке?

Comment: @GrayHoax, Я использую при регистрации

Comment: SQL инъекции не страшны?

Comment: Какой web сервер используется? Нужен error.log.

Comment: @GrayHoax, я забыл включить error.log. Бывает такой ошибка: Warning:  array_walk() expects parameter 2 to be a valid callback, function 'array_sanitize' not found or invalid function name in Z:\home\site.kz\www\core\functions\users.php on line 4
Fatal error:  Call to a member function query() on a non-object in Z:\home\site.kz\www\core\functions\users.php on line 11

Comment: Автор, вы можете сами перевести данное сообщение?

Comment: @GrayHoax, ваше не знаю уже голова начинает болеть...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно сделать `global $con;`, а то не будут выполняться запросы.

Вообще, для отладки стоит использовать XDebug и Eclipse. Если не хочется разбираться, хотя бы делать `echo 1;` построчно. Там где не будет выводиться `1` — там и ошибка)

UPD:

```
<?php
function register_user($register_data) {

global $con;

    array_walk($register_data, 'array_sanitize');
    $register_data['password'] = md5($register_data['password']);

    $fields = '`' . implode('`, `', array_keys($register_data)) . '`';
    $data = '\'' . implode('\', \'', $register_data) . '\'';

    $insert = "INSERT INTO users($fields) VALUES ($data) ";
    mysqli_query($con,$insert);
    $last_id = mysqli_insert_id($con);
    $update = "UPDATE users SET url = '".$last_id."' WHERE id = ".$last_id." ";
    mysqli_query($con,$update );
}
?>
```

В этом примере я предполагаю, что у автора уже есть коннектор к MySQL, открытый и с правильными параметрами. Если же нет, то считаю, что автору сначала надо ознакомиться с документацией по работе с БД. Начиная с [этой страницы](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php).

**UPD2:**

```
<?php
function register_user($register_data) {
    global $con;
    array_walk($register_data, 'array_sanitize');// не понимаю что за callback, видимо формирует правильный массив
    $register_data['password'] = md5($register_data['password']);

    $fields = '`' . implode('`, `', array_keys($register_data)) . '`'; // Ну ведь не очень безопасно
    $data = '\'' . implode('\', \'', $register_data) . '\'';

    $insert = "INSERT INTO users($fields) VALUES ($data) ";// Интересно, что через 2 строки используется уже слияние)
    $con->query($insert);// Здесь была функция расширения mysqli далее считаем, что используется именно оно
    $last_id = $con->insert_id;//Последняя вставленная строка. Важно чтобы в таблице users был autoincrement
    $update = "UPDATE users SET url = '".$last_id."' WHERE id = ".$last_id." ";// не вот о чем я и говорил)
    $con->query($update);//снова запрос
}
```

?>

Comment: Покажите подробнее код пожалуйста я новичок и ничего не понял :)

Comment: Я внес изменения, думаю сейчас должно быть понятно. Если нет - сначала почитайте документацию. В любом случае, не стоит злоупотреблять вопросами без изучения материала самостоятельно.

Comment: global is evil.

Comment: Вроде да, но ничего не бывает по-моему у меня есть грамматический ошибка. Пожалуйста проверите!

Comment: Отсутствует указанная callback функция, нужно её добавить и понять что она должна делать. Рекомендую ознакомиться http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php